# Создание словаря из строк в файле на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как обработать фаил со строками:

```
#
#
flow monitor
##
start
 start command 1
 initialization process 56
 0656 ignore
  768 switch off
  87
#
init
 start flow master
  send
  receive
 config
#
#
stop
 stop process initialization
 pool empty
#
end
#
```

Чтобы с помощью python получить словарь вида для всех комманд в корне:

```
{
    "flow monitor": [],
    "start": {
        "initialization process 56": [],
        "0656 ignore": [
            "768 switch off",
            "87"
        ],
        "start command 1": []
    },
    "init": {
        "config": [],
        "start flow master": [
            "send",
            "receive"
        ]
    },
    "stop": {
        "pool empty": [],
        "stop process initialization": []
    },
    "end": [],
}
```

Поправьте пожалуйста:

```
def get_int_vlan_map(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
            dict3 = {}
            commands = []
            for line in file:
                    if line.startswith('#'):
                            pass
                    if line[0].isalpha():
                            commands.append('{}'.format(line.strip()))
                            dict3 = dict.fromkeys(commands, [])
                    elif line.startswith(' '):
                            subcom = line.strip()
```

Comment: Ну для начала вложенности как есть)

Comment: А количество уровней вложенности не будет меняться? А почему `"flow monitor": [],` и `"end": [],` типа list, а `"init"`и `"start"` dict?

Comment: Если два уровня вложения то верхние команды - ключи словаря, нижние списки. Если три уровня то последний вложенный - список, остальные словари.

Answer (score 2):

Парсер для структуры в вопросе.

Входные данные:

```
text = """\
#
#
flow monitor
##
start
 start command 1
 initialization process 56
 0656 ignore
  768 switch off
  87
#
init
 start flow master
  send
  receive
 config
#
#
stop
 stop process initialization
 pool empty
#
end
"""
```

Код (с версии 3.6 вместо `OrderedDict` можно использовать `dict`):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict


def get_level(text_line: str) -> int:
    match = re.search('^( +).+', text_line)
    level = len(match.group(1)) if match else 0

    return level + 1


def parse(text: str) -> dict:
    result = OrderedDict()

    last_level_1 = -1
    last_level_2 = -1

    line_list = text.splitlines()

    for i in range(len(line_list)):
        line = line_list[i].rstrip()
        if not line or line.startswith('#'):
            continue

        key = line.lstrip()
        level = get_level(line)

        if level == 1:
            level_data = OrderedDict()
            result[key] = level_data
            last_level_1 = level_data

        elif level == 2:
            level_data = []
            last_level_1[key] = level_data
            last_level_2 = level_data

        elif level == 3:
            last_level_2.append(key)

    # Препроцесс для замены на первом уровне пустых словарей на пустые списка
    for k, v in result.items():
        if not v:
            result[k] = []

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = parse(text)

    import json
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Консоль:

```
{
    "flow monitor": [],
    "start": {
        "start command 1": [],
        "initialization process 56": [],
        "0656 ignore": [
            "768 switch off",
            "87"
        ]
    },
    "init": {
        "start flow master": [
            "send",
            "receive"
        ],
        "config": []
    },
    "stop": {
        "stop process initialization": [],
        "pool empty": []
    },
    "end": []
}
```

Comment: Мастер, спасибо огромное, работает. Я не профессионал в питоне, но по-моему все гораздо проще.

Comment: @zloyrok, если ответ понравился, поставьте его как правильный

Comment: я б с удовольствием но репутация маленькая

Comment: @gil9red Оффтоп: А это нормальная практика импортировать библиотеки не в начале скрипта, а там где они в первый раз потребуются?

Comment: @Jazzis, хз, сейчас я стараюсь в начале скрипта писать импорты. Раньше казалось это удобным, мол импортирую когда нужно и использую, плюс функции/классы легко переносить между модулями, т.к. они самодостаточные. Но сейчас думаю, лучше заранее импортировать и получить ошибки при отсутствии каких-то внешних модулей, чем при вызове какой-то из функций с таким внутренним импортом. Это мало касается модулей "из коробки". А так можно посмотреть как это в стандартной реализации интерпретатора сделано (спойлер: импорт в начале файлов): https://github.com/cython/cython/search?l=Python&p=1&q=import

Answer (score 2):

```
from pprint import pprint

def controller(filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
                dict3 = {}
                level1 = ''
                level2 = ''
                for line in file:
                        if line.startswith('#'):
                                pass
                        elif line[0].isalpha():
                                level1 = line.strip()
                                dict3[level1] = {}
                        elif line.startswith(' ') and line[1].isalpha():
                                level2 = line.strip()
                                dict3[level1][level2] = []
                        elif line.startswith('  '):
                                dict3[level1][level2].append(line.strip())
                for k, v in dict3.items():
                    if not v:
                        dict3[k] = []
                return dict3

result = controller('controller.txt')
pprint(result)
```